# Rails 2.x app on RubyMine 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, upgrade, rubymine

i've upgraded to rubymine 3.1 and now rubymine take all project as rails 3 project, but the mine are not. Does anybody of you face this problem. Ruby mine fires up this message, when i try to run application

**Run configuration error:** Rails 2.x launcher found instead of Rails 3.x one. You need '/script/rails' 
script to launch Rails server. Please update server launcher according to Rails 3.x documentation

My final state is i can run rails 2.x app server from rubymine

Do you know how to achieve that?

Comment: I use Rails 2.3 and RubyMine 3.1 and I haven't had this problem. Is Rails 2 specified in environment.rb?

Comment: yes, it is 
    RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.10' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this problem using Rails 2.3 and RubyMine 3.1 -- my solution was to look at the project settings (File -> Settings) and select Ruby SDK and Gems. Look through your attached rails gems. I had both rails 2.x and rails 3.x gems attached to my project.

Comment: yes, this worked for me (just removing the incorrect gems), i had tons of 2.3.8 and 3.0.3 gems for my project.  I fixed by starting by removing the rails 3.0.3 one and then let rubyMine prompt for for all the others such as actionMailer for 3, etc. (3 or 4 screen steps)

Comment: Hi, I have rubymine 3.2.4 and I dont see the File/Settings, has it moved?

Comment: @Joelio ruby mine -> prefrences -> ruby sdk