# Rails 2.x launcher script was found instead of Rails 3.x one a lot in RubyMine

Tags: ruby, rubymine

keep getting this message in rubyMine

Comment: c'mon the error's right there. The q was clearly obvious to the readers below who gave a great answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have the rails 2.x gem attached to your RubyMine settings. Go to File > Settings and take a look at Ruby SDK and Gems. Make sure you have rails 3.x selected, and not something else.

Answer (score 2):

I think the solution here should solve your problem:

[Rails 2.x app on RubyMine 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090318/rails-2-x-app-on-rubymine-3-1)